# Application Updates by users NOT super users

Tags: permissions, updates

What permission should I assign to a "NOT superuser" user, so that they can update a specific application, for example Chrome? This is very useful since these applications are updated very regularly.
From already thank you very much.

Comment: important question: who installed chrome and what method? chrome can update itself.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Sorry for NOT indicating the correct package, the package is google-chrome-stable, it was installed by the administrator, and this is used because it has the functional Google synchronization function. The installation process is through dpkg -i google-chrome-stable. Therefore, when updating, it requires supervisor rights.

Comment: @user535733: The installation was carried out on a company where it was detected that activating automatic updates caused problems with some applications and drivers, the same as Windows, given this problem is that there is a test machine where it is updated and tested before proceeding with the others. operating machines.

Comment: Please avoid commenting on your own question. Instead, edit your question to clarify or improve the original question. Comments are not intended for conversation. Comments are intended to help you improve your question until it is answerable.

Comment: @tecunpsjb but then you are asking the wrong people....you need to ask your admin ... that person is in charge. All our solutions are likely a violation of your in-house protocols :)